Use native module in worker_threads in electron
We are using better-sqlite3 in our project. And we are using it in a worker thread.
It is a native module that is built on compile time (.node file).
In our development environment it's possible to use it in the worker_thread without problems. When we require it in production in the main.ts file it's running fine.
But when we try to use it in a worker_thread and in production we get the error:
Error: Cannot find module 'better-sqlite3'
It's just the native module. We are able to include non-native modules in worker_threads just fine.
We are struggling with this for days now and have no clue where to look or what could possible be the problem so it would really help if somebody could give it a hint.
Could it be a code signing issue? But then we wouldn't be able to require it from the main.ts file in production would we?
